# In which way I can use Laravel Eloquent Relation to solve my issue

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I've created a table named - 'clients' which has Many to Many Relationship with another table named - 'categories'.

I've 4 tables with their columns below :-

- '**users**' - id, category_id
- '**categories**' - id, name
- '**categories_users**' - id, user_id, category_id (**Many to Many**)
- '**requests**' - id, category_id

I want to grab those requests which has same categories as of users categories which are saved in the 'categories_client'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Requests would need to `belongTo()` a Category, something like the following should then work.

```
// Create empty collection
$requests = new Illuminate\Support\Collection();

// Loop through all the categories a user has and merge their requests
//    into our empty collection
$user->categories->each(function($category) use (&$requests) {
    $requests->merge($category->requests);
});
```

I don't believe there is a built in relation to support this through a pivot table, like there is `hasManyThrough()`